# include js file on html

Tags: javascript, include

At first, I'm sorry about my English :))

I had some problems when i try to include file .js on index.html

```html
<script src "../src/man/js/Generator.js"> </script>
```

but when i press F12 for debug, i get an error like:
"failed to load '../src/man/js/Generator.js' from source/src/man/js/Generator.js"
this is file's structure:

[image]

so how can i deal this?

Comment: You're missing an `i` in `/src/man/js`.

Comment: oh, i'm sorry, i only write wrong the link on this post, but on my project, i wrote correctly "../src/main/js/Generator.js".
i want to use "resourceroot", but i dont know how to use it?

Comment: Can you post a complete error message with all the details it gives you?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `=`:

```
<script src="../src/main/js/Generator.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you must have check your Path.
`<script src "../src/man/js/Generator.js"> </script>`
won't work.
but,
`<script src "../src/main/js/Generator.js"> </script>`
will work.
Man, you forget the 'i' in 'main'

Answer (score 0):

Please add equal src = "path"

```
<script src="../src/man/js/Generator.js"> </script>
```