# My Javascript file and jQuery aren't linking to my html file (everything is in the same folder and there are no typos)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have just started coding and I have encountered a problem that seems very obvious. I wrote an HTML code in an HTML file and a CSS code in a CSS file. I have placed both in the same project folder.

To animate my website, I decided to write a Javascript code in a .js file using jQuery. I downloaded the latest version of jQuery into that same folder as all my other files of that project.

The CSS linked just fine, but not the Javascript. (I needed some text in Russian, so I followed the instructions from an answer in this forum). I am using Atom.

Heres my code (the file is long, so I won't include the full contents, just the javascript element... I literally made one to test it out but nothing seems to work) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ru">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script  src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="out"><p>Test</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is what i wrote on main.js to see if it works :

```
$(document).ready(function() => {
    $('.out').on('mouseover', ()=>{
      $('.out').hide();
    });
});
```

So as you can see I am trying to make this part hide when the mouse goes over it. I also tried with 'click' and without the event. I didn't type anything else in main.js... was there supposed to be something that notifies it what document this goes into?

Furthermore, in the HTML, I also tried to specify the type (although not necessary). It also didn't work.

I don't know if I made typos or anything... I suspect that it may be because I put them all in the same project file. The project file in sitting on my desktop. Could that be the cause of the problem?

EDIT
I have changed my main.js file to :

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('.out').on('mouseover', ()=>{
      $('.out').hide();
    });
});
```

But it still doesn't work...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [include js file on html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289016/include-js-file-on-html)

Comment: If you are using chrome, open developer's tool , go to network tab and relaod the page, & check if files are loading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove `=>` from `$(document).ready(function() => {` and it will work (either it is in separate js file or added in HTML page itself)

Working snippet:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.out').on('mouseover', ()=>{
    $('.out').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ru">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><!--used live jquery library to make it working -->
</head>
<body>
  <div class="out"><p>Test</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

***Note:- You can do like this also***

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
  $('.out').on('mouseover', ()=>{
    $('.out').hide();
  });
});
```

Running Output:- https://jsfiddle.net/npthjwu1/

***A bit more cleaner approach:-***

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('.out').on('mouseover',function(){ 
     $('.out').hide(); 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: thank you. 2, 3 and 4 are all checked. But I'm not sure how to check the first one or how to change it... Should I create a new file and start over? Is there any way that I can check if my computer doesn't have a problem with it? (I use a mac with the latest update)

Comment: right click on folder and check folder permission. you can change from there too. plese check my code what i have given in comment. it's completely different from my answer:- `$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.out').on('mouseover',function(){
    $('.out').hide();
  });
});`

Comment: it was the code! I copy pasted your code and pressed enter to make it easier to read and it worked! For some reason it only recognizes a code written with **function(){}** and not **()=>{}** its very strange! i'm not sure why this is happening

Answer (score -1):

remove => from `$(document).ready(function()`

Answer (score -3):

I think the problem comes with the anonymous function syntax that you are passing in as jQuery event handlers. You are trying to use both the old school JavaScript lamba and the new ES lamba syntax.

Try removing the old school JavaScript anonymous function syntax `function(){}`, and use the new ES style `() => {}` (since it is the latest, which is supported by modern browsers) as follows...

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('.out').on('mouseover', () => {
        $('.out').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you, I just did that, but it still doesn't add the javascript code into the html file...

Comment: try adding the following inside the `<head>` tag... `<base href="/">`

Comment: open browser tools in your respective browser, and view the network tab to see whether the main.js file is getting loaded successfully or not. then view the console tab, to see whether there are any errors

Comment: indeed there is an error on the first line : **$(document).ready( ( ) =>{** It looks like it doesn't identify jQuery.. it says that its a syntax error : Unexpected token ')'

Comment: and then in your network tab, is jquery being successfully loaded ?